# How to make a hamburger menu show a dropdown list

Tags: bootstrap-4, hamburger-menu

I'm learning Bootstrap 4 and I've successfully got the content in my navbar turning into hamburger menus at smaller screen sizes just like I want. The problem I'm running into now is that one of the things that becomes a hamburger menu is a Browse button that shows a dropdown list at larger screen sizes:

[image: Browse button click]

And it does become a hamburger menu at smaller screen sizes, but when I click the hamburger menu the Browse button appears just to the right of it and that's not exactly what I want to have happen:

[image: Hamburger menu click]

I'm trying to eliminate a click at smaller screen sizes and have the hamburger menu show the dropdown list directly when clicked, instead of having to click the hamburger menu then click the browse button that pops out.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!-- browse button hamburger menu button -->
<a class="navbar-toggler border" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarBrowseButton">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </span>
</a>

<!-- browse button collapse content -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarBrowseButton">
    <a class="btn btnBrowse dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Browse</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Games</a>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Popular Lists</a>
```

I took out the ARIA stuff for simplicity and I've tried giving my `dropdown-menu` an id and changing the `data-target` with varying degrees of success, but it's still now working how I want.

Comment: In short, you have problem with small screens and your need is when you click on hamburger menu, browse have an open menu?

Comment: yes, the dropdown menu appears when you click the Browse button and that's exactly what I want to have happen when you click the hamburger menu, I want both clicks do the same thing, show the dropdown menu

Comment: see my answer bro

Comment: I saw it, but the Browse button is still popping out when I click the hamburger button and overlapping my header text and I was trying to get it to only show the menu, not the Browse button. I have it looking okay and not overlapping now by fiddling with the z-index. Thanks for that.

Comment: Well, I like this behavior because I can have numbers dropdowns when screen shrinks. I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JS for it.

Added `bg-dark navbar-dark` classes for toggler showing purpose.

```js
$('#navbarBrowseButton').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
  $('#navbarBrowseButton .btnBrowse').click();
});

$('#navbarBrowseButton').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
  $('#navbarBrowseButton').collapse('hide');
  $('#navbarBrowseButton').dropdown('hide');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- browse button hamburger menu button -->
<a class="navbar-toggler border bg-dark navbar-dark" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarBrowseButton">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon text-center">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </span>
</a>

<!-- browse button collapse content -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarBrowseButton">
  <a class="btn btnBrowse dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Browse</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Games</a>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Popular Lists</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Nisharg it's working, but the Browse button is still popping out to the right of the hamburger menu on mine and not underneath like it does in your snippet. Any idea how I can make it appear underneath? Because I would actually prefer that, it looks nicer imo

Comment: I think, its because you have custom CSS on your page and its conflict your code

Comment: it is in a `<div class="row">` I wonder if that's affecting the direction?

Comment: give `flex-column` to your parent class, I think it will works and if not, post fresh new question